# Get Featured Image in pseudo elements( i.e. :before or :after) - WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, pseudo-element

I want to get WordPress featured image in pseudo elements. I've used it in inline style using following code

```
<?php
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($whatWeDo_post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
?>
```

`<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumb_url[0]; ?>);">`

But I want to use it in pseudo elements

Comment: Just give the div a class and write `.class::before {background-image: ...` in the css. (Or if you can write to a css stylesheet with PHP, create a `<style>` element on the page.)

Comment: Have you considered using PHP for your stylesheet? It'll only work if you have you main styles in a secondary file that isn't `style.css`. Name a new file `images.css.php`, give the file an HTTP CSS header, and then place the PHP call in the stylesheet.

Comment: Other option is to read the CSS file into PHP, and print it inline, as mentioned by Mr Lister.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1

Your main concern here is caching. You don't want to write the `background-image` style into your external `.css` file because it will probably change on every page. But you don't want to clog up your main HTML file with lots of extra inline styles.

Your best bet is to split off just what you don't want cached (the `background-image` and the rest of the styles). We want to inline just what shouldn't be cached, and leave the rest as an external `.css` file.

Say the styles relevant to your Featured Images container are something like this:

```
figure::before {
    display:block;
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0;
    background-image:url();
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Just leave your `.css` file exactly the same format (don't use `.css.php`), but pull out the `background-image` line.

Then in the header, place this:

```
<style>
    figure::before {
        <?php $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($whatWeDo_post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
        background-image: url(<?php echo $thumb_url[0];?>);
    }
</style>
```

---

## Bonus - Another Option Just for Fun

The second option is to use a `.php` file with a `.css` HTTP header. I like to name my files something like:

```
styles.css.php
```

**Advantages**

This lets you use WordPress variables and data, as well as the entire power of PHP, directly in your stylesheet. But it's still sent to the browser as a `.css` file, so you can enqueue it like normal. It's the easiest to implement. Note, be sure to include the global `post` object.

**Disadvantages**

Do you use resource caching? If you `.css` files are cached, you're going to run into a problem because the file won't change on each page. In your specific case, the Featured Image will be different on each page. If you don't cache, it should be fine, but you absolutely should be caching, so you should probably skip this option.

---

## Tweak on Bonus Option

If you like Option 1 but you do cache (which you should), you can take a middle ground. Create your file the same as above, something like:

```
styles.css.php
```

Instead of enqueueing it the **[official way](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)** using `wp_enqueue_style`, you can read the file with PHP's `include` function.

Create a function in your `functions.php` file:

```
function writeInlineCSS() {

    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/styles/styles.css.php';
}
```

Then in your header, add:

```
<style>
    <?php writeInlineCSS(); ?>
</style>
```

The CSS will be pulled in and written inline.

**Advantages**

Caching won't be a problem. Also you won't have a large render blocking `.css` resource. Plus the advantages from Option 1.

**Disadvantages**

You are including potentially a massive chunk of CSS inline. Possibly too much.

Comment: Thanks bro, I've already used this code before seeing this post :)

Answer (score 1):

This is pulling from Mr Lister's comment, but here's a method of doing this. It's not the best way to structure the html, but it should work:

```
<?php $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($whatWeDo_post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<style type="text/css">
.myDiv:before{
    background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb_url[0]; ?>');
    content: '';
}
</style>
```

I'm not sure if you'll run into some browser compatibility issues with older browsers and the  tag outside of the , but it should work in modern browsers.